# Scheduled backup never run in Plesk 12.0.18

Tags: plesk, remote-backup

Scheduled backup never run in Plesk 12.0.18.

Right user, group and permission:

```
ll /etc/cron.d/plesk-backup-manager-task
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 111 Nov 19 15:54 /etc/cron.d/plesk-backup-manager-task

cat /etc/cron.d/plesk-backup-manager-task 
10,25,40,55 *   *   *   *   root [ -x /opt/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng ] && /opt/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is the configuration on web admin panel:

[image]

On database the record seems to be correct.

```
mysql> select * from psa.BackupsScheduled;
+----+--------+----------+------------+---------------------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+------------+---------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------------------+
| id | obj_id | obj_type | repository | last                | period | active | processed | rotation | prefix | email | split_size | suspend | with_content | backup_day | backup_time | content_type                 |
+----+--------+----------+------------+---------------------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+------------+---------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------------------+
|  1 |      6 | domain   | ftp        | 2016-01-05 19:03:41 | 604800 | true   | false     |        4 |    abc |       |          0 | false   | true         |          2 | 03:00:00    | backup_content_all_at_domain |
+----+--------+----------+------------+---------------------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+------------+---------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In BackupsSettings table I've the right value, indeed backups work properly if I run them manually.

I also checked log files related to plesk backup manager (http://kb.odin.com/it/111283). But I can see only backup executed manually.

---

Running /opt/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng manually nothing happens.
It should be normal, because the cronjob is executed each 15 minutes so I think /opt/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng read tasks on database, and execute the task only if there is one scheduled.

Now I don't know if I should change the cronjob to match the task scheduled for 3:00 am of each tuesday:

```
0,15,30,45  *   *   *   *   root [ -x /opt/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng ] && /opt/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute /opt/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng manually? Backup is creating in this case?

Comment: No, it isn't. Please take a look at updated question.

Comment: Looks like issue in backupmng, but it's an compiled C binary which doesn't write logs. Think it's a bug, so consider to contact Plesk support.